# Carrierwave mounted to Rails 4 PostgreSQL array attribute

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

Since Rails >= 4.0 adds [support for PostgreSQL array data types](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-notable-changes) I was wondering if anyone already played with [carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) attachments mounted to array attributes instead of join tables when a model should have multiple attachments.

What I got in mind is something like

```
class AddPicturesToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :pictures, :text, array: true
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :pictures, PictureUploader, array: true
end
```

Comment: have you been able to do something like this?

Comment: @acrogenesis - not yet.

Comment: any progress on this? It seems the official carrierwave documentation does include some facility for using arrays to store the information on multiple files -https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#multiple-file-uploads - given Rails 4 + Postgres, it seems like a natural marriage to me.

Comment: Thanks for the link @marcamillion. I'll give it a show asap

Comment: Has anyone had any progress on this yet?

Answer (score 1):

Check https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1548

switch to the github version of the carrierwave gem

`gem 'carrierwave', github: 'carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave'`

Use mount_uploaders instead of mount_uploader in your class as described in the carrierwave wiki.

`mount_uploaders :pictures, PictureUploader`

remove the, array:true at the end of the mount_uploader.